# what does docker version name means?

Tags: centos, docker, yum

Following [docker document](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce-1)
When I get the `To install a specific version of Docker CE, list the available versions in the repo` step

```
yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
 * updates: mirrors.aliyun.com
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Installed Packages
 * extras: mirrors.aliyun.com
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.5-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.5-3.el7                    @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.4-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.3-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.2-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.1-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            3:18.09.0-3.el7                    docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.3.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.2.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.1.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.0.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            18.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
```

There is not any information about what the middle column means.
There are some version suffix with `centos` like `17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos`
And some with `el7` which is demonstrated as

> The list returned depends on which repositories are enabled, and is
>   specific to your version of CentOS (indicated by the .el7 suffix in
>   this example).

I guess the `@docker-ce-stable` is something special, like the default version. And what does the `3:` means in `3:18.09.5-3.el7`? I think it's mainly about `18.09` right?

Can't find any document about any of this. Or is it something about `yum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number before the colon, `3:` in this case, is an epoch number, used to handle situations where the version number needs to be decreased. This could be the result of a beta or RC build getting out with a higher version number that wouldn't allow a normal upgrade to the GA release. I believe you need this in any commands selecting version numbers, but you can otherwise ignore this when trying to understand which version you have installed.

The important part of that version number is `18.09.5` which tells you:

- `18.05`: the major release number from docker's rolling releases, they are roughly based on the date of the first patch of the release, so 18.05 refers to May 2018
- `5`: the patch number, where fixes are released without new functionality

Note, directly from docker, you can run:

```
docker version
```

To see both the client and server version numbers.

Comment: what about the `@` ?

Comment: The `@` I'm not sure of, hopefully someone will chime in on that.

Comment: docker-ce-3:19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64, what us the first 3 stand for?what is the second 3 stand for?

Comment: @Dolphin I believe this is covered by the answer above, in the first sentence and then the first bullet.