# what is the docker version number docker-ce-3:19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64 stand for

Tags: docker

I get the docker version number: `docker-ce-3:19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64`.That ce means community edition, but 3 stand for what? 19.03.12 stand for version number I can find from [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases).But what is the second 3 stand for?el7 is stand for Enterprise Linux 7?Why the version number make so complex?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://serverfault.com/q/964152/351549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`el7` stands for "Enterprise Linux 7" it refers to Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 7. It is used by RHEL distros and any distro that has as upstream RHEL (e.g. CentOS).

For versioning you should read:

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Versioning/
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Naming?rd=Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Multiple_packages_with_the_same_base_name

More details:

- `docker-ce-3` stands for Docker Community Edition. Why the first `3`? Because Docker changed the versioning. See: https://serverfault.com/a/964298/30946 and https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/17.03/#17030-ce
- `19.03` is the year (2019) and the month (March). See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/17.03/#17030-ce
- `12` is the patch level from docker
- `3` is the patch level from Red Hat
- `x86_64` is the machine architecture Intel 80x86 with AMD 64bit extension.